# Mysql select first and last row every work-day (after specific time) for every user, for every room

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql DB that stores user room access log with the following schema http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c3fc/3

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `access_log` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `room_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `access_log` (`user_id`, `created`, `room_id`) VALUES
(1, '2019-08-05 01:56:40', 10),
(2, '2019-08-05 02:56:51', 11),
(3, '2019-08-05 03:32:49', 11),
(4, '2019-08-05 08:34:50', 12),
(4, '2019-08-05 08:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-05 08:38:52', 10),
(3, '2019-08-05 10:46:02', 11),
(1, '2019-08-05 10:47:12', 12),
(1, '2019-08-05 11:06:27', 13),
(1, '2019-08-05 11:56:40', 10),
(2, '2019-08-05 12:56:51', 11),
(3, '2019-08-05 13:32:49', 11),
(4, '2019-08-05 18:34:50', 12),
(4, '2019-08-05 18:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-05 18:38:52', 10),
(3, '2019-08-05 20:46:02', 11),
(1, '2019-08-05 20:47:12', 12),
(2, '2019-08-05 22:56:51', 11),
(3, '2019-08-05 23:32:49', 11),
(4, '2019-08-06 01:34:50', 12),
(4, '2019-08-06 01:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-06 01:38:52', 10),
(3, '2019-08-06 02:46:02', 11),
(1, '2019-08-06 08:47:12', 12),
(4, '2019-08-06 08:34:50', 12),
(4, '2019-08-06 08:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-06 08:38:52', 10),
(3, '2019-08-06 10:46:02', 11),
(1, '2019-08-06 10:47:12', 12),
(1, '2019-08-06 11:06:27', 13),
(1, '2019-08-06 11:56:40', 10),
(2, '2019-08-06 12:56:51', 11),
(3, '2019-08-06 13:32:49', 11),
(4, '2019-08-06 18:34:50', 12),
(4, '2019-08-06 18:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-06 18:38:52', 10),
(2, '2019-08-06 22:56:51', 11),
(3, '2019-08-06 23:32:49', 11),
(4, '2019-08-07 01:34:50', 12),
(4, '2019-08-07 01:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-07 01:38:52', 10),
(3, '2019-08-07 02:46:02', 11),
(1, '2019-08-07 08:47:12', 12),
(4, '2019-08-07 08:34:50', 12),
(4, '2019-08-07 08:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-07 08:38:52', 10),
(3, '2019-08-07 10:46:02', 11),
(1, '2019-08-07 10:47:12', 12);
```

I want to select the first and last record of every user for every day for every room, in order to track attendance. The query I came up with is:

```
select user_id, room_id, date(created), min(created) first, max(created) last
from `access_log`
group by user_id, date(created), room_id;
```

The problem with this query is it assumes the start time of each day is `00:00:00` and end time is `23:59:59`. I would like to set a custom start time to, say `08:00:00`. How can I do that? Would appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: What should the desired result look like? Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can offset the date/time value:

```
select user_id, room_id,
       date(created - interval 8 hour) as date,
       min(created) as first, max(created) as last
from `access_log`
group by user_id, room_id,
         date(created - interval 8 hour);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c3fc/14) is the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Your MySQL probably does not support window functions so you have to use correlated subqueries:

```
select user_id, room_id, date(date_sub(created,interval 8 hour)), 
(select created from access_log as a2 
  where a1.user_id = a2.user_id and a1.room_id and a2.room_id and date(date_sub(a1.created,interval 8 hour)) = date(date_sub(a2.created,interval 8 hour)) 
  order by created limit 1) as first, 
(select created from access_log as a2 
  where a1.user_id = a2.user_id and a1.room_id and a2.room_id and date(date_sub(a1.created,interval 8 hour)) = date(date_sub(a2.created,interval 8 hour)) 
  order by created desc limit 1) as last
from `access_log` as a1
group by user_id, room_id, date(date_sub(created,interval 8 hour))
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work sure

```sql
select user_id, room_id, date(created), 
(select created from access_log as a2 
  where a1.user_id = a2.user_id and a1.room_id and a2.room_id and cast(a1.created as date) = cast(a2.created as date) 
  order by created limit 1) as first, 
(select created from access_log as a2 
  where a1.user_id = a2.user_id and a1.room_id and a2.room_id and cast(a1.created as date) = cast(a2.created as date) 
  order by created desc limit 1) as last
from `access_log` as a1
```